# How to split a large dataframe into train-test in python

Tags: python, keras, bigdata, train-test-split

I have a desk data frame in python, and it is very big. I would like to split this data frame to train-test in order to apply it to an auto-encoder which is written in Keras. But, when I run the code bellow, I got memory problem.

```
import dask_ml.model_selection
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = dask_ml.model_selection.train_test_split(df[[columns]],
                                                    df['label'],test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
```

I think the solution is to split the dataframe batch by batch, but I don't know how. So please let me know what is the best solution.

Thanks